# Add an extra table every time the row is updated

Tags: php

I basically have an input system where people enter data and the data is printed in a specific order in a HTML table.

I have some code which works fine below except that every time the row is updated, the table is edited instead adding a new table with the data. Also when i refresh the data disappears?

My code is below:

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM rumours";
        $query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $band = $row['band'];
                        $title = $row['Title'];
                        $description = $row['description'];
                         }
$sql="INSERT INTO rumours (band, Title, description)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 if (mysql_query($sql, $connect)) {
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> $title  </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class = 'td1'> $description </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
    }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_query() twice, it will insert duplicate data in your table! Call it once and store the result, then re-use it. Or use the "else" part of the "if" statement. And generate the table inside the while loop, and do the insertion before the selection, and.... brain exploding :/

Answer (score 0):

You are only generating the table from the *inserted* db rows, not all of the db rows in the db table. To do that, you have to `echo` the table code for each of the found rows as well:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rumours";
$query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $band = $row['band'];
  $title = $row['Title'];
  $description = $row['description'];
  echo "<table border='1'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td> $title  </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class = 'td1'> $description </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
}
$sql="INSERT INTO rumours (band, Title, description)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
/* ... Code truncated to save space */
```

Comment: @JamesSables See the updated answer. Just forgot to `echo` the `table` for each row.

Comment: i have two different scripts, one for posting and one for seeing the posted data,i have used the include statement to see the table, would that work?